# When, during the model building process, should I split dataset into training ang test one?

Tags: machine-learning, data-transformation, dataset, methodology

There are many steps throughout the process of building a model, like data cleaning, feature extraction, etc. My question is, when exactly should I split data set into two separatable datasets? In the beginning, just before model learning or maybe at a different moment?

Comment: Very beginning.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: Less chance of data leakage and overfitting.

Comment: Yea, but Isn't it better to have knoweledge of the whole dataset when filling missing values?

Comment: Absolutely not, that is overfitting, you are using the "test" set values to fill values in your training set which you will then use to predict the test set. Think of your test set as a yet unavailable sample, which you will get in the future. Right now you only have your training set and you fill missing values based on your available data.

Comment: Does the same apply to feature engineering? And how should I perform cross-validation, considering your approach?

Comment: Yes, same applies for feature engineering. Cross validation is done on the training set also, or yet another set the so called validation set.